# How can I convert a relative link in Mechanize to an absolute one?

Tags: ruby, hyperlink, mechanize, absolute-path, relative-url

Is there is a way to convert a Mechanize relative-link object to another one which contains the absolute URL.

Mechanize must know the absolute link, because I can call the `click` method on relative links too.

Answer (score 23):

You can just merge the page uri (which is always absolute) with the link uri:

```
page.uri.merge link.uri
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not specific to Mechanize, but an easy way would be to use the base URL in the `<base>` tag and add it to the relative URL to use for whatever purpose you want. This generally works.

But, then I'm not sure if you could call the `click` method on that since I don't know Mechanize that well.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [resolve](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/mechanize/2.7.3/Mechanize/HTTP/Agent#resolve-instance_method)

Example:

```
require 'mechanize'
agent = Mechanize.new

page = agent.get(url)

some_rel_url = '/something'

url = agent.resolve(some_rel_url)
```

Keep in mind that the other answers provided do not take into account all the possibilities to get the base url as described [here](https://www.freesoft.org/CIE/RFC/1808/13.htm)

Basically this:

[image: Image from that link]